# onCreate() throws NULL Pointer exception

Tags: android, android-theme, setcontentview, appcompatactivity

I have been trying to port my application to support pre Lollipop devices and the action bar seems to be missing when I run the application on pre L device. It was mainly because `getActionBar` was returning NULL and I think from the posts I have read on SO, I was supposed to move onto `getSupportActionBar()`, which I did and changed my Splash Activity to use this theme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

But when `onCreate(Bundle)` gets invoked for my Splash Activity and `setContentView()` is called, I now get the following exception:

```
02-18 14:38:42.750 27331-27331/com.airwatch.tunnel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.airwatch.tunnel/com.airwatch.tunnel.ui.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.applyFixedSizeWindow(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:487)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:287)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
```

Initially, I was getting errors as listed in [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity) , but after I changed the `theme` as described above, I am getting the above crashes. Can someone please provide some pointers on how to go about fixing this? I couldn't find anything specific to the problem I am facing right now. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Below is the Java code setup in onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    initViews();
    mProfileReadyReceiver.registerReceiver();
    super.onCreate(arg0);
}
```

Comment: Added the onCreate() Java code.

Comment: Can someone please mention why the downvote? Did I not provide enough details or did not perform enough research before posting the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    initViews();
    mProfileReadyReceiver.registerReceiver();
    super.onCreate(arg0);
}
```

With

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    initViews();
    mProfileReadyReceiver.registerReceiver();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`super` should be the first call from this method.

Your method should look like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    initViews();
    mProfileReadyReceiver.registerReceiver();
}
```

Comment: How do you know I copied and pasted when solution is one? Why can't it be copy of code in the post and sequence is changed?